# Cannot update major version for my npm package

Tags: javascript, npm

I've been working with npm just fine up until now updating versions of my package from 1.0.0 to 1.1.11 and today I wanted to update the major varion (i.e. to 2.0.0)

I did everything by the book (I think...). Everything seems to be in place: package.json is updated, git tag is pushed etc. but npm still claims that the latest version of my package is 1.1.11.

Can anyone help me diagnose what am I doing wrong? This is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-vs-repeat

Comment: Please provide actual actions performed instead of `something was done`.

Comment: I have published 6 versions since 2.0.0 trying things out so right now I'm doing:

`npm version patch`
`git push`
`git push --tags`
`npm publish`

Comment: npm even sends me an email that a new version has been successfully published...

Comment: Hi kamilkp!

A new version of the package angular-vs-repeat (2.0.6) was published at 2018-03-16T12:54:41.153Z from
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. The shasum of this package was xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.

If you have questions or security concerns, you can reply to this message or
email support@npmjs.com.

npm loves you.

Comment: Nevermind looks like it was just an npm huge laaaaaag.